# Why doesn't this 767 nose paint line up with the rest of the paint?

Tags: paint, nose, boeing-767, radome

Looking at this Boeing 767 you'll notice that the nose paint is not lined up with the rest of the paint. But the same model with the same paint scheme on the second image is fine. What is the reason for this?

[image: Paint not aligned]

[image: Paint aligned]

Comment: It seems to match the paint from an [alternative paint scheme](https://cdn.airplane-pictures.net/images/uploaded-images/2016/3/19/689507.jpg) which had a straight line between the blue and white sections lining up with the wing.

Comment: This is one of the types of questions that on the surface looks uninteresting but then you realize that you are equally intrigued yourself. There's definitely more than meets the eye here.

Comment: @user985466 -- Since we don't know that the photos were taken around the same time, we don't know whether it is the same plane or not.  Generally speaking,  your edit may sense, but *not for the specific reason you gave when you made the edit* (you said they weren't the same plane because the radome paint was different.)  "Just saying..."  But more to the point, the OP may actually know for a fact that these *are* the same plane.  If so, he/she should roll back the edit -- (and possibly add content to explain how these *are* known to be the same plane.)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It has a nose radome from another aircraft installed. The aircraft that donated the radome was painted with older TUI livery, where the blue/white border is straight, and in a slightly different place. The joggle in the paint scheme is the edge of the radome. If you put that radome back on the aircraft it came from, the paint lines will match up.

The original radome for that airplane was probably damaged by a bird strike or something on the ground, and they robbed one from another airplane (probably one that was down for maintenance) to dispatch it.

Comment: Here's an image of the livery with the straight line - https://www.planespotters.net/photo/1384414/ph-oyj-arke-boeing-767-304erwl

Comment: Lol, nice. I would have guessed it was a photo stitching error!

Comment: @PhilMiller it can happen with any aircraft almost. A KLM 737 flew around for months once with a Transavia nose for example.

Comment: Any nose cone is better than no nose cone :)

Comment: @EricNolan seems like you've accidentally posted the same image twice

Comment: As you look closer at the two planes there are windows closer to the nose of the planes . Also the red letters are over the windows in one pictures but not the other . And there are other things on the planes that are different .. So I think that if you looked at other pictures you would find the nose paint is the same .. Some lined up , some not lined up .. As long as it flies who cares ?.

Comment: @somebody thanks for pointing that out.  Here's the correct url for the alternate image of the plane in question - https://www.planespotters.net/photo/1380959/g-obyk-tui-airways-boeing-767-38aerwl